# Is there a business class lounge at Noumea Tontouta airport?

Tags: airports, lounges, new-caledonia, nou

For my upcoming trip to Noumea, the only seats left on the way home were in business class, so I'll be suffering the hardship of flying back at the pointy end... As I've had to pay more than planned for the ticket, I'd like to make the most of being in business. I'm therefore wondering if there is a business class lounge at Noumea Tontouta airport, and if so, do Qantas passengers get access to it?

I've tried searching the [airport website](http://www.tontouta-aeroport.nc/index.php), but I can't seem to find anything about a business lounge there. However, on the [floor plan](http://www.tontouta-aeroport.nc/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=41&Itemid=78), in the top right there's a room marked `VIP lounge`:

[image]

Is this a lounge that Qantas business class passengers get access to, or is there simply no business lounge at an airport this small?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Qantas website, there is one and you should have access to it -

> Location: 
>   Departure hall Level 2 - (Lift is located between the duty free collect and the bar).
>
> Hours: 
>   2 hours before departure
>
> Operated By: 
>   Aircalin - Salon Hibiscus Lounge*

.

> **Lounge Access and Eligibility**
>
> *International Business*
>
> Next onward flight that day must be a Qantas flight.
>   One guest allowed and must be travelling with the member on the same flight.

http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/lounge-locations/noumea/international/associated-lounge-aircalin/global/en?loungeCategory=qcLounge